# Getting the complex solutions to $y''+k^{2}y=0 $ using Laplace method

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, laplace-transform

Asking the hardcore Laplace wizards here.

I know that the general Complex valued solution to $$y''+k^2y=0\ \ is \ \ \ y(x)=C_1e^{ikx}+C_2e^{-ikx}$$

However, upon trying to reach the same conclusion using the Laplace method for differential equations:
$$(s^2+k^2)Y(s)=sy(0)+y'(0) \rightarrow Y(s)=y(0)\frac{s}{s^2+k^2}+y'(0)\frac{1}{k}\frac{k}{s^2+k^2}$$
and therefore:
$$y(x)=y(0)cos(kx)+y'(0)\frac{1}{k}sin(kx) = (\frac{y(0)}{2}+\frac{y'(0)}{2ki})e^{ikx}+(\frac{y(0)}{2}-\frac{y'(0)}{2ki})e^{-ikx}=Ae^{ikx}+A^*e^{-ikx} \in \mathbb{R}$$ which is only REAL VALUED and therefore misses the complex solutions.

I'm assuming I'm discarding some assumption made in the process of solving the differential equation using laplace, but I can't figure out where it all goes wrong. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$ are real. Regardless of the method, the solution to this equation with real initial conditions will be real for all $x$.

To see this if $$y = C_1 e^{ikx} + C_2 e^{-ikx}$$

then $$\begin{align}y(0)&= C_1 +C_2\\
y'(0)&=ik(C_1-C_2) \end{align}$$

which has the solution

$$y = y(0)\cos(kx) + \frac{y'(0)}{k}\sin(kx)$$

If you let $y(0),y'(0)\in\mathbb{C}$

then $$\frac{y(0)}{2}+\frac{y'(0)}{2ki}\neq \left(\frac{y(0)}{2}-\frac{y'(0)}{2ki}\right)^*.$$

For example, take $$y(0) = i$$
$$y'(0)=0$$

Then $$\frac{y(0)}{2}+\frac{y'(0)}{2ki}= \frac{i}{2}$$

while

$$\left(\frac{y(0)}{2}-\frac{y'(0)}{2ki}\right)^* = -\frac{i}{2}$$

Comment: well this does indeed make more sense thank you for your time!